# XML Parser for Ruby

Tags: xml, ruby, parsing, sax, xerces

Looking for something similar to xerces for parsing an xml file in ruby.  I saw the native processor REXML and another called hpricot (though I can't find any documentation on hpricot, the links all appear to be dead).  I'm looking for something that would parse an xml document via SAX2 in ruby.

TIA.

Comment: Most of the hpricot links are broken because _why was the developer, and he managed to almost completely remove himself from the internet a few weeks ago. GitHub has a mirror up now (http://github.com/whymirror/hpricot/tree/master)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been successful with the [Nokogiri SAX Parser](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/SAX.html)

Comment: Nokogiri really is the best thing out there. It's nice and clean, without too much magic.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from those already mentioned, the other mainstream alternative is probably [LibXML](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two fast BLAST XML parsers for Ruby, which are easy to understand examples of iterative lazy parsing, using a C extension for the low-level XML parsing. Both are based on libxml2 and Nokogiri. Nokogiri because the performance rocks. See http://biogems.info to find the two parsers.